# Handle no-unused-styles for dynamic stylesheet

Tags: react-native, eslint

In react-native, using dynamic styles like so:

```
const myComponent = () => {

    const styles = createStyles(theme)

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        </View>
    )
}

const createStyles = theme => StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.background,
    },
})
```

How do i avoid getting eslint warnings from react-native/no-unused-styles ?

Comment: any solution?...

Comment: @RajeshN check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74889376/5401352

Comment: you did same issue is that eslint giving error

Answer (score 9):

Assigning **Stylesheet.create** to a variable with the same name as the style variable inside your component solves the issue.

```
const myComponent = () => {

const styles = createStyles(theme);

return {
    <View style={styles.container}/>
}

const createStyles = theme => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: theme.background,
    },
  })
  return styles;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not the nicest solution but the only one that came to my mind since the eslint is being wrong here...

```
const styles = ({ color }: ListDecorationProps) =>
  StyleSheet.create({
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-native/no-unused-styles
    bullet: {
      borderRadius: 999,
      zIndex: 5,
      width: 20,
      height: 20,
      backgroundColor: color,
    },
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately if you have multiple styles in the stylesheet you would have to do that for each one.